# How can i reverse text in python?

Tags: python, string, methods

I want to reverse a text which is in variable in python but I'm not sure if we have string method for this problem or not
How can i reverse the text with strings method?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "*I'm not sure if we have string method for this problem or not*" You don't need to guess, you can check the Python docs for all the string methods: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods (spoilers: there is no reverse method).

Comment: One way to *"kill two birds with a nuclear-powered sledgehammer"* would be to use `reversed` iterator to join back to a str: `''.join(reversed('hello world!'))`

Comment: On that page, reverse() is indeed listed as a method. Indeed, "reverse" is mentioned exactly 20 times at the documentation URL given.

Answer (score 1):

A simple google search would let you find how to work with lists and variables. You can use: [::-1] at the end of the list or variable to reverse it. Then you can customize the iterators if you need to increment at different intervals.

```
var = "123"
print(var[::-1]) # "321"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
txt = "Hello World"[::-1]
print(txt) 

# or like this

def my_function(x):
  return x [::-1]

mytxt = my_function("I wonder how this text looks like backwards")

print(mytxt)
```